# Is it possible to use a variable for an SQL object fetch call instead of its string name?

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array

I am wondering if it is possible to store the field names from a table into an array then loop through another table using the previous array data as the object for the 2nd sql loop i.e. $foo->$bar, $bar being the index in the array.

I do hope you understand what I mean here, I am having trouble explaining it myself.

So over to you wonderous masters of PHP and SQL to explain how its done properly :)

```
// Connect to the database to gather all data pertaiing to the link in question
$assoResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM associate_users");
while ($assoRow = mysql_fetch_field($assoResult)) {
    $resultArray[] = $assoRow->name;
}

// Connect to the database to gather all data pertaiing to the link in question
$assoResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM associate_users WHERE id='$getID'");
while ($assoRow = mysql_fetch_object($assoResult)) {
    foreach ($resultArray as $row) { 
        $array = array(array( 1 => $assoRow->{'$row'}, 2 => $row, ),);
    }    
}
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Having worked on this further the problem only lies in

```
foreach ($resultArray as $row) { 
    $array = array(array( 1 => $assoRow->$row, 2 => $row, ),);
}
```

I just need the loop to add to the multi-dimensional array instead of re-writing it on eacj iteration of the foreach loop.

I am hoping this is easier an explantion of my problem :)

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that at the moment the above code will only show the last row of the table and cannot assign the object fetch "$assRow->{'$row'} part.

Comment: Try to describe in plain English what you're trying to achieve (with an example of input and expected output). Now neither your code, nor your description seems to make any sense to me.

Comment: The array at the end should hold all the row data for a specific user selected from a table, having just done further testing I have realised that the problem lies in the foreach loop, and that it is re-setting the multidimensional array on each loop i.e. Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => foo [2] => bar)) ... Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => foo2 [2] => bar2)). I just need it to add and iterate the array index on each loop.

Comment: i still don't entirely get what you're going for, but i can say pretty confidently that you should query the table only once.  once you pull down the whole table everything should be done in the PHP.  i get how using WHERE clause seems convenient, but array_filter can do all the same things

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

`$array[] = array(array( 1 => $assoRow->{'$row'},  2 => $row, ),);`

Comment: Sadly that just creates an extra dimension on the array it does put all the correct data into the array but it creates as many new arrays as indexes in the array.